# Why does the set of integer vectors in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$ constitute a lattice?

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

I can almost see that this is true for the following reason:

Let $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}$ be the set of all integer vectors in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. Then any finite linear combination with integer coefficients of these vectors is again an integer vector in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. This is almost a lattice, except I'm using too many "basis vectors". And I don't see how I can trim the number of $\mathbf{x}_i$ to just the dimension of the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Why do you say it is 'almost' a lattice? You just showed it is a lattice. I am confused about your comments on dimension/basis.

Comment: To me a lattice is a set of the form $\{\mathbf{Kx}:\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^k\}$ for some matrix $\mathbf{K}$. But I don't see how to reduce the set of all integer vectors in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$ to a single matrix.

Comment: A lattice is an additive group that is isomorphic to some $\mathbb Z^n$.

Comment: I was thinking of them like this:
https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/introduction.pdf

Comment: Besides, I have at best shown that the integer vectors in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$ constitute an additive group. I haven't demonstrated that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: That definition shows precisely that a lattice is an additive group that is isomorphic to some $\mathbb Z^n$. In that description, $n$ is just the number of linearly independent vectors. I guess you have in fact not demonstrated that it is isomorphic to some $\mathbb Z^n$, but that should be farily easy. Do you think you can do that?

Comment: I've been failing for two days now, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, a highly general result is as follows:

> **Theorem.** *Let $n\gt 0$ be a positive integer, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then there exists a basis $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, an integer $d$ with $0\leqslant d\leqslant n$, and positive integers $m_1,\ldots,m_d$ such that $m_1|m_2$, $m_2|m_3,\ldots,m_{d-1}|m_d$ and such that $m_1a_1,\ldots,m_da_d$ is a basis for $H$. In particular, $H$ is free and finitely generated.*

In particular, $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^d$.
You can see a proof this in [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117691/subgroups-of-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group-without-torsion/117810#117810), with an explanation of an unclear part in [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169293/structure-theorem-for-finitely-generated-abelian-groups-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

While the idea that $H\sim \mathbb Z^d$ for some $d$ sounds fairly intuitive, that one can produce a basis with the divisibility property is not so obvious.
You might have heard of the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) for matrices, which provides an algorithm for finding exemplars of the theorem given generators for $H$.

Comment: I've been mulling on this some more. Doesn't the following also work?

Consider the set of all lattices generated by integer vectors in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. These lattices can be partially ordered using the subset relation. This partial order has infima (intersection) and suprema (direct sum) and therefore constitutes a lattice in the order sense. If you may, we have a lattice of lattices. Now this lattice has an obvious upper bound, namely $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Hence it has a maximal element which is the desired lattice.

Comment: Is such a maximal element, in principle, unique? Does the choice, in principle, not matter?

Comment: If there were two maximal elements then their direct sum would again be a lattice in the nullspace containing both maximal elements, contradicting the assumption that they were maximal.

Comment: Sounds good -- that's a maximum!

Comment: On second thought, I don't know if the assertion that the direct sum of two lattices again constitutes a lattice is as straightforward as it sounds or whether this requires an argument that is again as complex as the one you linked to.

Comment: By direct sum of lattices $L, L'$ do you mean the set $\{l + l',\,|\,l\in L, l'\in L'\}$?

Comment: Yes, it's all possible integer combinations you could build using basis vectors from either lattice. The question is if these vectors can be reduced to a basis if linear dependencies begin to show up. This is almost the first problem I was struggling with again, but now there's only finitely many vectors to consider.

Comment: That the set above is a lattice is obvious. It is clearly closed under addition.